# Thermal paste loses effect in one day?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

Recently I replaced my thermal paste and everything seemed fine at the beginning, temperature and idle was 49 degrees, but then over the day the temperature would slowly increase, stabilizing at around 74 degrees at idle, and if I shut the computer down and next day I boot up it would be at 100 degrees. I do not feel any lag nor does it shut down or bluescreen.

If I replace the thermal paste again the cycle continues. I thought that it was my own problem so I
followed numerous tutorials on how to apply but still does not seem to work. I also thought that it was my paste's problem so I bought a thermal grizzly kryonaut but it still doesn't seems to do the job.

Comment: There's more to cooling than just the paste, isn't there?

Comment: Does the paste have published techincal data? Look into it; might be you have situation that isn't covered, i.e. might be you're using the wrong paste.

Comment: Yes, I am using a Corsair Hydro Series H115i, the pastes I've used are Arctic Cooling MX-4 and Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut respectively @GerardH.Pille

Comment: @Hannu In that case what would be the right paste for Corsair Hydro Series H115i? My CPU is i7 6800k.

Comment: And your sure the pump is doing its job?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille On Corsair Link it shows a 30 degrees temp with 1472 rpm on the fan and if I touch the pipe, one is quite hot and the other one is quite cold, I think that indicates it's working?

Comment: In which case (one hot) it's currently doing its job, isn't it?  Your degrees, F or C ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille C

Comment: Your question needs "details or clarity".  I'm sure you know what's missing.  I don't.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I genuinely do not know... I asked because I am trying to find an answer

Comment: But, according to Tom's Hardware, you do have a problem.  They manage to run a game around 30°C.  Any way to increase the speed of the pump?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille https://i.imgur.com/Xu0y3dE.png, I have changed the mode to max on whichever I can.

Comment: If you're really desperate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63OlQrkaqgY  Shake it!